# query select options do not append to select

Tags: jquery, append

receiving a JSOn response in a script

```
[{"text": "alpha","selected": false},
 {"value": 2, "text": "beta", "selected": false },
 {"value": 3, "text": "delta", "selected": false }]
```

I am trying to generate the corresponding options and inserting them in a modal window

```
    <!-- Groups Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="groupsModal" tabindex="-1" access_level="dialog" aria-labelledby="groupsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
      <select multiple="multiple" id="groups-selector" name="user-groups[]"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote the function :

```
   function initGroupSelect(groups) {
     var options = "";
     $.each(groups, function(index, group) {  
       options += "<option value='"+group["value"]+"'>"+group["text"]+"</option>";
     });
     console.log("options:  "+ options);
     $('#groupsModal div.modal-content select').append(options);
   }
```

when I show the modal , there is no option in it ( no options in the html source)

the console shows the correct options string :

```
options:  <option value='1'>alpha</option><option value='2'>beta</option><option value='3'>delta</option>
```

what's missing ?
thanks for feedback

=== update 1 
the initiGroupSelect function is called  :

```
  $('#user-addTool').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#groups-selector').multiSelect(); // init the group selector in groups modal
    var ajaxUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + "/users/new.json";
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.get(ajaxUrl, function(data){
      $('#userModal div.modal-content').html(data["html"]);  // fill inthe user form modal
      initGroupSelect(data["groups"]);   // fill in the groups modal    
    });    
    $('#userModal').modal('show');  // show user form
    $('#groupsModal').modal('show');  // test only, should be hidden
  });
```

Comment: Note, first item in array does not have `value` property set , would return `undefined` for `value` property of first `option` . Where is `initGroupSelect` called ? Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: I can display in the console the property (name' of the selector... 
the function is called upon success of an ajax request to fill a modal  see my question update..